# Need to send 1 request in N seconds in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, throughput

I want to send 1 request per 10 seconds then reduce it to 1 second per 5 sec like this i want to test performance of the http request. I do not have concern with Threads.

I have tried two different things.

1. Constant throughput timer
   Thread count - 5
   Target Throughput - 12.0
   Calculated throughput - all active threads in current thread group

Result : [image: Jemter screenshot with constant timer]

But i want only one request on **11:36:28.337** then second request is on **11:36:33.337** like this.

2. Throughput shapping timer 
   Start RPS & End RPS = 0.2
   Thread group - 5

Results :[image]

This result is also not satisfactory.

Please provide me the correct configuration. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either reduce number of threads to 1 or use reasonable ramp-up time as:

- Constant Throughput Timer is precise enough on **minute** level, don't expect it to pause the threads from the first second, let your test run for a while
- If you need throughput limitation to be applied from the very beginning of your test make sure 2nd thread (virtual user) will be added not earlier than on 61st second of the test, i.e. set ramp-up time in the Thread Group to something like `300` given you kick off 5 threads.

Despite its name Constant Throughput Timer doesn't need to be "constant", you can define the desired throughput via JMeter Property using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(throughput,)}` and amend the property value using i.e. [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) or even outside JMeter via i.e. [Beanshell Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server), check out [How to Adjust the RPS in Your JMeter Test via the Command Line](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-adjust-the-rps-in-your-jmeter-test-via-the-command-line) guide for more details.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thank for your help. I can not use only one thread, because my request will take almost 10-15 seconds to get response. So if i will use only one thread then jmeter will not fire second request after 5 seconds.